Excel VBA Sum Columns Based on Header Title
I have a spreadsheet with about a thousand rows and several columns that have the same header titles. E.g. Principal in column AD, AG and AJ etc.  Is there a macro that I can use to detect the header title and sum the values in the cells by row?

This sounds like it's easily accomplished with a SUMIFS formula. Any reason you're trying to use VBA?

Yes - the columns change position from time to time, so I thought a vba code would work best.  Do you disagree?

SUMIFS will work regardless of positions changing.

This formula SUM all the columns which has an identical name in the example Header1
A2:G28 the range of the data
= SUM(CHOOSECOLS(A2:G28,TOROW(IF("Header1"=A1:G1,COLUMN(A1:G1),1/0),3)))

In row 29 there is the sum of columns only for checking
